# Will there be a component of acceleration perpendicular to the surface along which a particle moves?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

[image]

A particle is sliding in a cone maintaining contact with it all the time. Analyzing the situation in spherical coordinates I was able to find that in the total acceleration of the particle there will be a component along $\hat{\theta}$ ,where $\theta$ is the polar angle(here $\theta=\alpha$ ),the equation is

$\ddot{r}=\left(\ddot{r}-r \sin ^{2}\theta\dot{\phi}^{2}\right) \hat{r}$+$(2 \dot{r} \dot{\phi} \sin \theta+r sin\theta \ddot{\phi}) \hat{\phi}-r \dot{\phi}^{2} \sin\theta\cos \theta \hat{\theta}$

But looking it intuitively I feel that there should be no component along $\hat{\theta}$, because any component along $\hat{\theta}$  would pull the particle away from the contact with the cone.

Why is my intuition wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acceleration in the direction of the $\hat\theta$ vector does not mean that the $\theta$ coordinate component changes, because the coordinate system itself curves.

For instance, pure circular movement around the vertical axis (which is one form of movement along the cone) would mean acceleration horizontally in toward the axis, which is partly the direction of $-\hat\theta$, partly the direction of $-r$ (assuming the vertex of the cone is at the origin).

Comment: Hello Dear Arthur, Yes I understand your answer Thank u. also After thinking  since I posted it I've come to realize that IF I had only $-\hat\theta$ as the acceleration ,then the particle would leave the cone. Am I correct? ,

Comment: @Kashmiri, I am not sure, but I don’t think so. It seems to me that you could have a particle spiraling upward such that it remained on the cone and its acceleration was a constant $-\hat{\theta}$. Given the circular movement example, the acceleration is toward the $z$ axis,which is part $-\hat{\theta}$ and part $-\hat{r}$. Without that acceleration, the particle would increase in both $\theta$ and $r$, based on its instaneous velocity. It seems to me that if you remove only the $-\hat{r}$ component of the acceleration it would increase in $r$ but not $\theta$.

Comment: @Joe,If you like here is it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081219/motion-of-particle-with-acceleration-hat-theta

Comment: @Joe, suppose the particle was at rest in the cone and its acceleration was in  $\theta$, that surely for me will pull it away from the surface.