# Motion of particle with acceleration $\hat\theta$

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, locus

Suppose a particle has acceleration $a=-\hat\theta$ , how can I find its trajectory?( for simplicity lets take $v=0$)

I tried to convert $\hat\theta$ into cartesian ,but the expression turned to be large. Then I tried to attempt it in spherical but it was difficult to integrate with a varying $\hat\theta$.
Finally I tried to sketch it ,and it seems that it would spiral upwards.

Could anyone give me a hint how to approach this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As

$$
\vec a = (\ddot r-r\dot\theta^2)\hat r + (r\ddot \theta+2\dot r\dot\theta)\hat\theta
$$

the movement is described by

$$
\cases{\ddot r-r\dot\theta^2=0\\
r\ddot \theta+2\dot r\dot\theta=-1
}
$$

Follows a solution plot for $\dot r(0) = \dot\theta(0)=0, r(0) = 1, \theta(0)=0$

[image]

Comment: the plot at the start is nearly vetical so $\dot\theta(0)\neq0$

Comment: The plot is in cartesian coordinates $(x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta)$

Answer (score 2):

The acceleration is always perpendicular to the radius $\hat r$. So if the particle starts from rest, you are moving in a circle, faster and faster.
$$\ddot\theta=-1\\\theta=-\frac12t^2$$ If the initial velocity is not zero, then the motion is more complicated.